# How to define in my model an array of id from another table in mysql and sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I create an api in express.js, node.js, mysql and sequelize.

I have two models : Custom fields and Customer Types

Here is my customer type model :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const CustomerType = sequelize.define("customerType", {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    })

    return CustomerType
}
```

And there is my custom fields model :

```
const customerType = require('./customerTypeModel')

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const CustomField = sequelize.define("customField", {
        customer_type_ids: [
            {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                references: {
                    model: customerType,
                    key: "id"
                }
            }
        ],
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        system_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        type: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        required: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: true
        },
    })
    return CustomField
}
```

I need to have in my customField table an array of id from the customerType table.
For exemple i need to get a json like this :

```
{
 "id": 1
 "customer_types_ids": [ 
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Customers",
     "description": "Customers",
     "user_id": "123456"
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "Leads",
     "description": "Leads",
     "user_id": "123456"
   }
],
 "user_id": "123456",
 "system_name": "firstname",
 "title": "Firstname",
 "type": "text",
 "required": true
}
```

How should I structure my custom field Model to be able to have a json like this in return?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're expecting a One-to-Many relationship between `CustomField` and `CustomerType`. In this case, `CustomerType` owns the relation, so there is a reference to `CustomField` in the relational table of `CustomerType` called `customFieldId`.

```
// customerType.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const CustomerType = sequelize.define("customerType", {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });

    return CustomerType;
}

// customField.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const CustomField = sequelize.define("customField", {
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        system_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        type: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        required: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: true
        },
    });

    return CustomField;
}

// db.js
...
const CustomerType = require("./customerType.js")(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
const CustomField = require("./customField.js")(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);

CustomField.hasMany(CustomerType, { as: "customer_types_ids" });
CustomerType.belongsTo(CustomField, {
    foreignKey: "id",
    as: "customFieldId",
});
```

This should define two relational tables with a One-to-Many relationship. The following code can be used to load a `CustomField` with all its `CustomerType`s.

```
CustomField.findByPk(id, { include: ["customer_types_ids"] });
```

Comment: You think that i need to create the two models in the same file ?

Comment: @OrenCohen No definitly not! Of course you can also define `CustomField` and `CustomerTypes` in different modules and place the `hasMany`/`belongsTo` logic in a third one. The point is, that you need to realize a One-to-Many mapping. I'll update the code for the usage of different modules

Comment: Okay but i don't need to add this in the model? customer_type_ids: [
            {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                references: {
                    model: customerType,
                    key: "id"
                }
            }
        ],

Comment: @OrenCohen Not you don't. Just try the upper code. Sequelize assumes a primary key called `id` for both models and realizes the association based on these primary keys.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Did you know how i can update the associations table when i update a table ?

Comment: @OrenCohen In this scenario no joining/association table is used. The reference ist stored as part of the `CustomerType` table. So what do you mean?

Comment: A customerType can have many custom field and a custom field can have many customerType. 
So in my table customField_customerType i have the customField_id and CustomerType_id.
When i update a custom field, i can update the customerType related to this customField so i need to update in the assocation table (customField_customerType) also